# Uncaught ReferenceError: SearchAddress is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to make a google map API that has moveable points but also includes a search option to search address. I have gotten the draggable points but get a Uncaught ReferenceError: SearchAddress is not defined  at HTMLInputElement.onclick when I try and run this code. I cannot figure out how to get this to work. I have tried removing the SearchAddress function out of the other InitMap function but still Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Draggable directions</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");

var moveloc1 = {lat: 55, lng: -7.3};
var moveloc2 = {lat: 55, lng: -7.1};



function initMap() 
{
    console.log("error checker1");
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();      
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 55, lng: -7.3}  // Australia.
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer
    ({
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
    });

    directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() 
    {
        computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    });

    displayRoute(moveloc1, moveloc2 , directionsService,
    directionsDisplay);
  console.log("error checker2");
   function SearchAddress() 
    {
        console.log("error checker3");

        var locate1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
        var locate2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
        console.log(locate1);
        console.log(locate2);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'pass1': address}, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status == 'OK') 
            {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                moveloc1 = 
                ({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } 
            else 
            {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + 
 status);
            }
        });

    }
}

  function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display)
  {
    service.route
    ({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true
    },
    function(response, status)
    {
        if (status === 'OK')
        {
            display.setDirections(response);
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
  }

  function computeTotalDistance(result) 
  {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++)
    {
      total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
    }

 </script>

 </head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
<form>
Start<input class="textBox" id="pass1" type="text" maxlength="30" /> <br>
End<input class="textBox" id="pass2" type="text" maxlength="30" />
<input  type = "button" id="button" name="button" value="search" onclick = 
"SearchAddress()"/>
</form>
<p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
</div>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=AIzaSyBtQt_1BqPPuSdIbXTuYW9I8yNUGIItPuk&callback=initMap">
</script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: you had that typo in your sourcecode ? the document must start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: The code posted starts with <!DOCTYPE html> already.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
var geocoder;
var moveloc1 = {lat: 55, lng: -7.3};
var moveloc2 = {lat: 55, lng: -7.1};

function SearchAddress() 
{
    console.log("error checker3");

    var locate1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var locate2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    console.log(locate1);
    console.log(locate2);
    // adress must be defined
    geocoder.geocode( { 'pass1': adress}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == 'OK') 
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            moveloc1 = 
            ({
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + 
status);
        }
    });

}

function initMap() 
{
    console.log("error checker1");
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();      
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 55, lng: -7.3}  // Australia.
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer
    ({
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
    });

    directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() 
    {
        computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    });

    displayRoute(moveloc1, moveloc2 , directionsService,
    directionsDisplay);
  console.log("error checker2");

}

  function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display)
  {
    service.route
    ({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true
    },
    function(response, status)
    {
        if (status === 'OK')
        {
            display.setDirections(response);
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
  }

  function computeTotalDistance(result) 
  {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++)
    {
      total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: So functions within functions cannot be referenced like that?

Comment: This creates a Uncaught ReferenceError: geocoder is not defined
    at SearchAddress (index.php:60)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick error which is why I had it inside the Initmap. As far as I'm aware, geocoder must be declared when the map is declared.

Comment: they can be declared like this, but only when the outer function is called in your case initMap() ... so it looks like initMap() is not called e.g your maps script has not loaded yet and called the callback

Comment: try use `defer` attribute only, not `async`

Comment: Still throws a Uncaught ReferenceError: geocoder is not defined
    at SearchAddress (index.php:60)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.php:124)

Comment: Distance, dragging and directions all still work perfectly though.

Comment: still looks like initMap is not called, you could try your initial code without the async attribute

Comment: i made an update, also could it be you button submits the form? e.G a new request is made ?

Comment: There is already a log for console.log("error checker1");
Both this and error checker2 appear in the console. 

When search is pressed, error checker 3 is logged as well as the two values that are passed into the Console.log(locate1) and 2.

Comment: i made a working update, cheers just added var geocoder to the front and removed the var from the init function, so now it works until the logs of from and to

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Your problem is that you declared `SearchAddress` function inside of `initMap` function and you tried to access it from global scope (in the HTML element), which is impossible.

**Explanation:**

In fact a local functions and local variables can't be accessed from the global scope or from other functions. Note that in HTML elements events you can only access functions declared in the global `window`scope.

You need to declare it in the global scope so you can access it from all functions and from HTML elements.

**Note:**

You need to fix that problem with all your functions declarations in your code.